# print a list of json objects in html after retrieval from firebase ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

The code below is a simple function attached to an ion-button:

```
viewExpenses(){
  this.afd.list('/expenses').valueChanges().subscribe(res=>{
    this.expenseList = res;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  });
}
```

The log returns an example list of 1 json object.

```
[{"Amount":"100","Description":"asdjasidj","Expense_Date":"2018-06-12","Expense_Name":"opt","Farm_Name":"doodle"}]
```

What I don't understand is how do i print it in html now?

Answer (score 2):

Simply bind your variable into html using interpolation syntax, Like this -

```
 {{expenseList | json}}
```

If you want to display any specific key you can use it like this -

```
Amount - {{expenseList?.Amount}}
```